# Firestore: Creating a document with specified UID, eventually with set(), but without updating the fields

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider these lines:

```
        Map<String, Object> the_data = new HashMap<>();
        the_data.put("login", "Anonymous");
        the_data.put("avatar_is_defined", false);
        the_data.put("amount", 0.0);
        the_data.put("deleted", false);
        the_data.put("can_read_user", true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Initializing your data... Please wait until the screen appears.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        user_database_model.getReferenceToUser(signed_in_user_uid).set(the_data, SetOptions.mergeFields("")).addOnCompleteList[...]
```

First time the user signs-in, this `set` call must be executed and all these fields must be actually set in the document whose UID is `signed_in_user_uid`.

But, if the user signs-in again (*i.e.:* the document already exists), this `set` either must be ignored (not executed) (in reality it's impossible, see last paragraph), or its fields must not be updated (that's why I've unsuccessly intended by writing `SetOptions.mergeFields("")`).

**Is it possible to call a `set` function saying "Firestore, please create this document and fill it with the provided fields if it doesn't exist ; but if it already exist, just... don't do anything"?**

**Important: due to Firestore Security Rules**, I can't `get()` the document to know if it exists or not. (in the callback I would have call `set` only if it doesn't exist). So avoiding to call `set` (not executing it) isn't possible in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the user to be able to create their document once, and never update it, you can do so in security rules with:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      // Applies to writes to nonexistent documents
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

      // Reject writes to existing documents
      allow update: if false;    
    }
  }
}
```

If you want the client-side code to detect whether the document already exists, and create it if it doesn't, [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).